# Galaxy Stratosphere II Fn button stops working

Tags: keyboard

My Galaxy Stratosphere II's `Fn` button (on its physical keyboard) has stopped working.  I.E. pressing `Fn` and then `r` will normally produce a `-` (hyphen) character; instead, this combination just produces a `r` character.  What causes this, how can I make it work again, and how can I prevent it from ceasing to work?

Answer (score 1):

Realized that I changed the `keyboard type` from `Default` to English US.

This is under `Home` -> `Settings` -> `Language and input` -> `Physical keyboard` -> [the first option].  If something other than `sec_keypad`: `Default` is displayed, tap it, click `Set keyboard type`, and go through the entire list and uncheck anything that is checked.